# Sample size calculation for clinical trial

Tags: sample-size, clinical-trials

I am facing a problem regarding sample size calculation of clinical trial.

> Currently a drug is used at `2.5` mg for adult and `1.5` mg for
>   children and death rate is `0`. Now we want to reduce the drug level
>   to `1.0` mg for adult and `0.5` mg for children.

If I want to keep the death rate at same for new drug level then how many sample should we take to justify.

Comment: unrelated to statistics. dose higher-> more lethal. this depends on toxicology and what elements are in the drugs.

Answer (score 2):

You have a more difficult problem than it seems that you realize.  There is not a single answer to this problem - you are describing a non-inferiority trial.  You can't "prove" that the death rate stays at zero because you will have a confidence interval for a proportion, whose width depends on how much data exist to support your statement that the death rate is zero.

Here is a place to begin on reading about non-inferiority trials: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC59590

Unfortunately for you, non-inferiority trials often require much larger sample sizes than conventional superiority trials.  Good luck!